# How to set header layout in video view

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I'm working in video view that contain title layout. I have attached the header layout in video view. what is my problem is when i touch on video view both title layou and mediacontolls should shown, After some time both(title layou and media controls) should disappear. Simply whenever the media controlls show the title layou should show , then whenever media controlls disapper the title layou should disapper.

[image: this is the my video view]

**XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/playerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/share_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/twitter_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twitter_button"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/share_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/share_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/facebook_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#BF000000"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageBtnclose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/close_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoTitletv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="video title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageBtnclose"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageBtnclose" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
public class VideoAdPlayer extends Activity {
// private boolean vbBackkeyPressed = false;
private VideoView myVideoView;
private RelativeLayout myLinearClose;
LinearLayout shareLayout;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private MediaController mediaControls;
private int adshowTime = 30;
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
boolean MidrollPlayed = false;
YuMeInterface yumeInterface;
ImageButton imgCloseBtn;
boolean isPortrait = true;
ImageButton faceBookButton, twitterButton, shareButton;
public static VideoAdPlayer playerActivity = null;

public static Context playerContext = null;
public static int playedAdType = 1;
public static boolean isActivityrun = false;

boolean isPrerollAds;
boolean isPostrollAds;
boolean isMidrollAds;
boolean isShareClicked = false;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String myString = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    System.out.println(myString);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String playVideoUrl = "";
    String videoThumb = "";

    getActionBar().hide();


    playerActivity = this;
    playerContext = this.getApplicationContext();

    myLinearClose = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
    shareLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.share_layout);
    TextView videoTxtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.videoTitletv);

    faceBookButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
    twitterButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_button);
    shareButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share_Button);

    shareLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    videoTxtview.setText("DEFAULT TITLE");

    if (mediaControls == null) {

        mediaControls = new MediaController(VideoAdPlayer.this);

    }
    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.playerview);
    imgCloseBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnclose);

    progressDialog = createProgressDialog(VideoAdPlayer.this);
    progressDialog.show();

    imgCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            JSONObject msgPlayer = new JSONObject();
            try {
                msgPlayer.put("finished", false);
                YumeIntegration.callbackContext.success(msgPlayer);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finish();
        }
    });
    try {

        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(playVideoUrl));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
    playedAdType = 1;

    myVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!myLinearClose.isShown()) {
                if (!isPortrait) {
                    myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                myLinearClose.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isPortrait) {
                                 myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000);

            } else {
                if (myLinearClose.isShown()) {

                    if (!isPortrait) {
                        myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);

    myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int duration = myVideoView.getDuration();
            Log.e("total duration", String.valueOf(duration));
            final int totalSeconds = duration / 1000;
            final int postrollads = totalSeconds - 25;
            final int MidrollAdsShows = totalSeconds / 2;


            Log.e("total durationin secods", String.valueOf(totalSeconds));
            try {

                mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int currentTime = myVideoView.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        /*
                         * if (currentTime > postrollads &&
                         * !postRolladsInit) { postRolladsInit = true; try {
                         * yumeInterface.updatesSdkParams(3); } catch
                         * (YuMeException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                         *
                         * } */

                        if (currentTime > MidrollAdsShows && !MidrollPlayed) {

                            adshowTime += 30;
                            MidrollPlayed = true;
                            playedAdType = 2;
                            if (isMidrollAds) {
                                if (yumeInterface.sdkIsAdAvailable()) {

                                    myVideoView.pause();
                                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(VideoAdPlayer.this, AdView.class);

                                    startActivityForResult(mainIntent, 3);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 2000);

                if (!mediaControls.isShowing()) {
                    mediaControls.show();
                    Toast.makeText(VideoAdPlayer.this,"YES",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myLinearClose.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (!isPortrait){
                            myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    });

 myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mTimer.cancel();

            JSONObject msgPlayer = new JSONObject();
            try {
                msgPlayer.put("finished", true);
                YumeIntegration.callbackContext.success(msgPlayer);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            playedAdType = 3;
            // finish();
            if (isPostrollAds) {
                if (yumeInterface.sdkIsAdAvailable()) {

                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(VideoAdPlayer.this, AdView.class);

                    startActivityForResult(mainIntent, 3);
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            } else {
                finish();
            }


        }
    });

 public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context mContext) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    try {
        dialog.show();
    } catch (BadTokenException e) {

    }

    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
    // dialog.setMessage(Message);
    return dialog;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed here it is 3
    if (requestCode == 3) {

        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
        myVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(false);

    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shareLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        isPortrait = false;

        landscapeMode();

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        shareLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        isPortrait = true;
        myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        portraitMode();

    }
}

private void portraitMode() {
    isPortrait = true;
    faceBookButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    twitterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    shareButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (!mediaControls.isShowing()) {
        mediaControls.show();
        Toast.makeText(VideoAdPlayer.this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myLinearClose.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!isPortrait) {
                myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
}

private void landscapeMode() {
    isPortrait = false;

    if (!mediaControls.isShowing()) {
        mediaControls.show();
        Toast.makeText(VideoAdPlayer.this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myLinearClose.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!isPortrait) {
                myLinearClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }, 3000);

    faceBookButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    twitterButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!isPortrait) {
                if (!isShareClicked) {
                    isShareClicked = true;
                    faceBookButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    twitterButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    isShareClicked = false;
                    faceBookButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    twitterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: just add a textview in the beginning before your videview.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
<TextView
           android:id="@+id/item_vid_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Title"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:layout_gravity="right" />

Comment: I already have the text view. My question is  whenever the media controlls show the title layout should show , then whenever media controlls disapper the title layout should disapper.

Comment: textview.setVisibility(View.GONE); --   textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: how can i know when will the media controlls disappear...?

Comment: when user click play/pause and video play/pause, set textview to gone.

Comment: Okay Thanks I will try it